# How to mount Atmel mass storage device with unknown FS

Tags: filesystems, mount

I'd like to mount an ATMEL mass storage device (USB) so I can access the data that was recorded to the medical device I was wearing.

Below are the commands I've run and the corresponding outputs.

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.802765] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.802784] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.802850] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.820587] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.820606] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.820613] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   17.820891] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   18.177844] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   18.177858] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Nov  7 13:37:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   18.177892] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Nov  7 13:39:18 raspberrypi kernel: [  105.079798] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021d01
Nov  7 13:39:18 raspberrypi kernel: [  105.279732] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
Nov  7 13:39:23 raspberrypi kernel: [  110.319777] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021d01
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.329904] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.529832] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.530038] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760386] usb 1-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x1 has invalid maxpacket 128
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760411] usb 1-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x82 has invalid maxpacket 128
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760429] usb 1-1: config 1 interface 2 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x4 has invalid maxpacket 64
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760720] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=6132
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760756] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.760766] usb 1-1: Product: Atmel
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.783258] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.796442] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.885081] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.897924] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
Nov  7 13:39:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  126.897939] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.227046] random: crng init done
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.841156] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATMEL    Mass Storage MSD 0.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.847971] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 728832 512-byte logical blocks: (373 MB/356 MiB)
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.848837] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.873403] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov  7 13:39:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  127.895118] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

From this output I determined the disk was at /dev/sda but I'm not sure what the invalid max packet lines mean.

When I tried to mount:

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda /media/usb-drive/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

So I ran dmesg:

```
raspberrypi:~$ dmesg | tail
[1034.801104] F2FS-fs (sda): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0xffffffff)
[1034.801108] F2FS-fs (sda): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 2th superblock
[1108.115588] F2FS-fs (sda): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0xffffffff)
[1108.115606] F2FS-fs (sda): Can't find valid F2FS filesystem in 1th superblock
```

Then a ran a series of commands as suggested by other troubleshooting posts.

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda -l
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATMEL Mass Storage MSD (scsi)                                      
Disk /dev/sda: 373MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I'm not sure what it means by unrecognised disk label.

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo file -sL /dev/sda
/dev/sda: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Does this mean I can just copy the whole disk with dd as one file and then parse it with a python script?

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda -l

Disk /dev/sda: 355.9 MiB, 373161984 bytes, 728832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

More info...

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                           
mmcblk0                                                       
|-mmcblk0p2 ext4         673b8ab6-6426-474b-87d3-71bff0fcebc3 /
`-mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot  109A-9113                            /boot
```

...

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo strings -a /dev/sda | head -n 40
<ZioPatch>
 <Device SerialNumber="NNNNNNNNNN" FW="0005" HW="0004"></Device>
  <Layout PageSize="2048" ControlBlockSize="128" Endian="Little" BitOrder="LS">
  </Layout>
    <PatientData SampleRateHz="199.805" ADCmin="-1.50" ADCmax="1.50" SampleBits="10" PacketSizeBytes="5" ButtonPressResolutionMS="320" LeadOffResolutionMS="640"></PatientData>
    <Control>
    <!-- every page -->
      <DiagsArea Size="20"></DiagsArea>
      <AGCGainArea Size="1"></AGCGainArea>
      <AccelerometerArea Size="32"></AccelerometerArea>
      <ExtraArea Size="19"></ExtraArea>
      <FWversionArea Size="4"></FWversionArea>
      <ECCArea Size="2"></ECCArea>
      <!--impedance values array of int16-->
      <ImpedanceLevelArea Size="30"></ImpedanceLevelArea>
      <RealTimeClockArea Size="6"></RealTimeClockArea><!--24 hour clock-->
      <BatteryLevelArea Size="2"></BatteryLevelArea>  
      <!--least significant bit corresponds to the last sample-->
      <DigitalGainArea Size="4"></DigitalGainArea>
      <ButtonPressBitsArea Size="4"></ButtonPressBitsArea>
      <PageSeqNumberArea Size="4"></PageSeqNumberArea>          
    </Control>
</ZioPatch>
17091870B27FB400000027
Rec Length--
&irQ
fm^7
aXj 
`XF!
E=KS
6uT<    q
`h" 
%I:E
v]'1
f%!2
ein^
r\w%
t]7U
u]GM
u]WU
```

This last one looks promising, but not sure what the next steps should be in my exploration.

Comment: It seems the USB memory module is not that large... you may be well served to make a copy of it using dd...    `dd if=/dev/sda of=atmel.img`  Then you can play with the image file mounted as a loop device instead of the actual module itself. Like [this](https://major.io/2010/12/14/mounting-a-raw-partition-file-made-with-dd-or-dd_rescue-in-linux/)